# Pandas: change view of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
id      domain
111      vk.com
111      facebook.com
111      twitter.com
222      avito.ru
222      vk.com
```

Desire output

```
id    domain1    domain2   domain3
111   vk.com   facebook.com  twitter.com
222   avito.ru    vk.com      NaN
```

I try transpose `df.T`, but it works otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `pd.crosstab`

```
    pd.crosstab(index=df.id,columns=df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1),values=df.domain,aggfunc='sum').\
               add_prefix('domain')
Out[570]: 
col_0   domain1       domain2      domain3
id                                        
111      vk.com  facebook.com  twitter.com
222    avito.ru        vk.com         None
```

Comment: I like `crosstab` solutions ;-) +1

Comment: @MaxU just a additional question from me , why we need `crosstab`, `pivot` , `pivot_table` all here...for me they do not have too much different ..:-)

Comment: IMO, the more options OP would have the better ;)

Comment: @MaxU sorry for the misleading , I mean pandas API...keeping three similar function ....

Answer (score 2):

```
In [34]: df.assign(x=df.groupby('id').cumcount()+1) \
    ...:   .pivot(index='id', columns='x', values='domain') \
    ...:   .add_prefix('domain') \
    ...:   .rename_axis(None, 1) \
    ...:   .reset_index()
    ...:
Out[34]:
    id   domain1       domain2      domain3
0  111    vk.com  facebook.com  twitter.com
1  222  avito.ru        vk.com         None
```

or

```
In [38]: df.assign(x=df.groupby('id').cumcount()+1) \
    ...:   .set_index(['id','x']) \
    ...:   ['domain'].unstack('x') \
    ...:   .rename_axis(None, 1) \
    ...:   .reset_index()
    ...:
Out[38]:
    id         1             2            3
0  111    vk.com  facebook.com  twitter.com
1  222  avito.ru        vk.com         None
```